# SwiftUI List on macOS: highlighting content in the selected row?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, swiftui-list

In a SwiftUI `List`, when a row is selected, a blue selection is drawn in the selection, and foreground `Text` with the default `primary` color is automatically made white. For other views with custom colors, I'd like to be able to make sure they become tinted white to match the system apps. For example, see the blue dot on the selected row:

[image: list]

Example code:

```swift
List(selection: $selection) {
    ForEach(0..<4) { index in
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
            Text("Test")
        }
        .tag(index)
    }
}
```

Any tips on how to achieve the correct result here?

With `NSTableCellView`, there is the `backgroundStyle` property, but I couldn't find anything like this.

- I've searched all of the available environment variables, and couldn't find anything appropriate.
- I have also tried manually including an `isSelected` binding on a view for each row, but the selection binding is not updated by `List` until mouse-up, while the highlight is updated on mouse-down and drag, so this results in a flickery appearance and is not right either.

I'm also looking to customize not just a single SF Symbol image, but also a `RoundedRectangle` that is drawn with a custom foreground color that I want to become white upon selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Approach

- Use a Label for the cell

## Code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selection: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        List(selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(0..<4) { index in
                Label("Test", systemImage: "circle.fill")
                .tag(index)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Screenshot

[image: Highlighted Cell Image Color]

Comment: That's hugely helpful, thanks. And I think for 99% of cases, it will be the correct thing to do. It solves most of my cell's problems, but I still do have one additional case, though. That is a RoundedRectangle with a custom foreground color that I need to tint white on selection. So if there are any other ideas on how to do this for a custom shape with a custom color, that would be super helpful!

Comment: You could submit a feedback using the feedback assistant and attach a sample code to demo the problem using custom shapes. Also raise a TSI (DTS team), they might be able to help. In the meantime while you wait you could use one of the existing SF Symbols that closely resembles what you want `Label("Test", systemImage: "rectangle.fill")`

Comment: Per my test on iOS 16.4, only `Label` and `Toggle` can adapt to all 4 variants of the colors (light/dark x selected/unselected).